# How to delete iPad calendar events when no edit option appears

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar

How can I delete iPad calendar events when no edit button appears? Clicking on events only results in "details" button.

Comment: It sounds like you are subscribed to a calendar that you cannot edit. Check and see if the events where no edit button appears are all in one calendar.

Answer (score 6):

- Go to  Settings app → Passwords and Accounts and scroll down.
- The subscribed calendars should be there and click it and click delete account and you should be good.

Comment: Kari, welcome to Ask Different. When answering a question like this it is important to explain the reason why your steps are important, in this case because you suspect the issue is with a subscribed calendar. Also it's helpful to break down steps into bullet points.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. A malicious site created a calendar on my iPad and kept showing me alerts. There was even their server ip, so some interaction is possible. iOS should display a system message before approving such actions. Can’t trust their Calendar app after this so will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the ability to delete the event (it's a shared calendar) then the Edit button will not appear.

For such events, you should remove the shared calendar through **Calendars** at the bottom of the app, then **choose ⓘ** on the shared calendar and select **Delete Calendar**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the month calendar and double-click on the event.  It does not give you the option to delete but you can decline the invite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess there's no answer for this yet, this is how I did it

- Add a new calendar

  - on the Calendar app, select Calendars, Add Calendar
- On the event you're trying to delete, select the newly added calendar in the Calendar option
- Go back out to your calendars, and delete the Calendar you added on the first step
- Your event is gone gone

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of iCal tap Calendar and it will show you list of all events automatically put into your iCal that has no Edit option.  Select item and adjust here.